# IS to possible to auto call a function as soon as PHP script's execution is started?

Tags: php, function

Is it possible to trigger a call to a function as soon as any PHP script's execution is started ?

e.g.

```
<?php

Include 'a.php';
Include 'b.php';

?>
```

So what I want to achieve is as soon as a.php is included a call should be triggered to a function.

There should be something like [register_shut_down](http://goo.gl/x2cp3) but this function is executed at **script shut down time**.

Comment: Do you mean "when a script is started" or "when a script is included/required"?

Comment: Yes Yeroon, As soon as script is started

Comment: call that method in `__construct()`

Comment: __construct is called only when a class's object is created. I wanted to call it as soon as the script is included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, using a line in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "prepended.php"
```

Or inside you php.ini ofcourse, but I'd not recommend it if you host multiple websites on the same server.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that with:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

```
Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require() function, so include_path is used.

The special value none disables auto-prepending.
```

Comment: and btw i was 30 secs faster xD